# How to connect cakephp to SQL server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, cakephp

I tried a lot to connect cakephp to SQL server 2008 no luck has any body had any luck

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried using it, but you may find this link useful. http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/aa6da91e842e6e9f

[Here(http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/can_cakephp_work_with_mssql#answer4ceab432-2948-4f74-9105-1829d13e7814)](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/can_cakephp_work_with_mssql#answer4ceab432-2948-4f74-9105-1829d13e7814) is someone who has been able to connect to SQL Server 2008.

Chances are you can't connect using PHP. [This(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) will help you with tha.